# How do I reduce memory usage when isolating objects?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

I commonly create animations with large memory requirements. huge poly count and textures. What's the fastest way to isolate objects or collections to increase my frame rate to the specified number?

Comment: For a selection - Local View with \

Answer (score 2):

In the Outliner, open the Filters popover menu and turn ON the "Disable in Viewport" restriction toggle (the screen icon):

[image]

Then for any object or collection in the outliner, you can disable it with that icon. You can also animate it.
While the regular viewport hiding doesn't impact any performance, this one will reduce the load for Blender. But it's only for the viewport, not rendering.

[image]

For collections, you can even uncheck their checkbox to exclude them from the view layer:

[image]

Though not animatable, in addition to disable in viewport it also hides the collection's content in the outliner, making it cleaner to read:

[image]

And it works in rendering too.

Comment: Thanks but you should experiment with hiding objects. You will find it doesn't help frame rate.

Comment: It definitely [does](https://i.imgur.com/8G0XxxH.gif).

Comment: It just really depends on what you hide, as well as what is limiting your hardware, and the rest of your scene.

Comment: It's just that I tried to suppress every collection and still had low fps. What else could be processing when every collection is suppressed? rigid body? particles? ummm